# Why is n! called “n Fakultät”?

Tags: etymology, mathematics

I’m trying to conciliate the noun *Fakultät* in its meaning of *Fachbereich* with its meaning of the function *Faktorielle*, *n*! (i.e.  [Γ(*n*+1)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammafunktion)).

Even easier, maybe as follows. On the second meaning, forgetting that it has a synonym: Does *Fakultät* have to do with *fakultativ*, and therefore with *Möglichkeit*? That’s the only possible origin I can find so far.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich ählich wie "Potenz", irgendwas Großes ;)

Comment: The origin is Latin _facultas_ ‎= _power_, _capability_ (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fakult%C3%A4t)

Comment: Clarifying the intended meaning of “n!” by the use of the gamma function – classic.

Comment: Here is a similar discussion, with some more insights: [Why the name 'FACTORIAL'?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/why-the-name-factorial).

Comment: @k.stm Well, now I put a link to it :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der französische Mathematiker C. Kramp führte um 1798 den Begriff *faculty* bzw. *faculté* (dt. „Fähigkeit“) ein.<sup>[(1)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fakult%C3%A4t_%28Mathematik%29)</sup> Bei der Eindeutschung wurde dafür die im wissenschaftlichen Bereich übliche Endung *-ät* verwendet (wie z.B. in Universität). Es könnte einen Zusammenhang geben zwischen der Wahl des Begriffs *Fähigkeit* und der mathematisch dahinterstehenden Quantität von Möglichkeiten (denn Fakultät berechnet in der Kombinatorik die Anzahl der Möglichkeiten, *n* Objekte in einer bestimmten Reihenfolge anzuordnen).

> "... I have given it the name 'faculty'. Arbogast has substituted the name 'factorial' which is clearer and more French. ..." (Christian Kramp, preface to Elements d'arithmétique universelle, 1808)

Answer (score 4):

In [Wikipedia (deutsch)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fakult%C3%A4t) steht, dass "Fakultät" seinen Urspung im 15. Jahrhundert von lateinisch "facultas" „Befähigung, Talent“ hat; Lehnbedeutung „Wissenschaftszweig“ von altgriechisch δύναμις (dýnamis) → grc, eigentlich „Kraft, Fertigkeit“.

Auf der englischen Seite steht nur kurz "[The origin is Latin facultas ‎= power, capability](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fakult%C3%A4t)" (siehe auch [Pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/latein-deutsch/facultas)).

Ich kann kein Latein und ich weiß nicht, was Christian Kramp sich bei der Namensgebung gedacht hat, aber vielleicht hielt er n! für eine kraftvolle (powerful) Funktion.

Comment: Es ist schwer zu wissen, was Kramp sich gedacht hat. Ein wenig mehr Information zu seinen Arbeiten und der Fakultätsnotation finden sich auf der Kurzbiographienwebsite von St Andrews zu Mathematikern  unter http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Kramp.html . Dort kann man auch lesen, daß einige Mathematiker die Notation _n!_ überhaupt nicht gut fanden.

Answer (score 0):

Ich zitiere den ersten Absatz aus [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fakultät_(Mathematik)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fakult%C3%A4t_(Mathematik)) (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Die *Fakultät* (manchmal, besonders in Österreich, auch *Faktorielle* genannt) ist in der Mathematik eine Funktion, die einer natürlichen Zahl das Produkt aller natürlichen Zahlen (ohne Null) kleiner und gleich dieser Zahl zuordnet. Sie wird durch ein dem Argument nachgestelltes Ausrufezeichen („!“) abgekürzt. **Diese Notation wurde erstmals 1808 von dem elsässischen Mathematiker Christian Kramp (1760–1826) verwendet, der um 1798 auch die Bezeichnung faculté „Fähigkeit“ dafür einführte.**

Also:
Frage: Warum »n!«?
Antwort: Weil Christian Kramp, der Erfinder dieser Funktion, sich diese Notation ausgedacht hat.

Frage: Warum »n Fakultät«?
Antwort: Weil Christian Kramp sich diesen Namen ausgedacht hat.

Wer mag, kann gerne weiter fragen:

F: Warum hat sich Kramp den Namen »Fakultät« ausgedacht?
A: Weil er dieses Wort für geeigneter als andere Wörter hielt.

F: Warum hat sich dieses Wort durchgesetzt?
A: Weil andere Mathematiker es für geeigneter hielten als alle Alternativen, die ihnen möglicherweise in den Sinn kamen.

Comment: Darf ich den Minus-1-Werter um eine Begründung bitten? Findest du, meine Antwort würde die Frage (*Why is n! called “n Fakultät”?*) nicht beantworten? Hältst du meine Antwort für falsch? Stört dich etwas anderes?

Comment: Ich tippe mal auf einen nachtragenden Trottel. Hab ich anderswo auch schon abbekommen, aber der flog dann nach einiger Zeit ganz ohne mein Zutun raus und seine ganzen systematischen 'Strafbewertungen' wurden rückgängig gemacht. (Ich weiß aber nicht, ob Stack Exchange da auch so effektiv ist wie Duolingo.)

Comment: @HansAdler: ja, ist es (erfahrungsgemäß).

Comment: Ich befürchte, deine Antwort beantwortet nicht das Warum, sondern Wer und Wann damit anfing.

Comment: @Em1: Um deine Befürchtungen zu zerstreuen, habe ich nun explizit die Warum-Fragen und die dazugehörigen Antworten zu meinem Beitrag hinzugefügt.

Comment: Nimm's mir nicht persönlich, aber die Art, wie du heute Fragen beantwortet hast, gefällt mir gar nicht. Das gilt für diese hier, und für die "Zitat"-Frage. Auch wenn du eine Frage nicht so 'gut' findest, kann man sie in angemesser Weise beantworten; oder vielleicht besser gar nicht.

Comment: Auch wenn viele "Warum"-Fragen eher nicht gut sind, finde ich diese hier übrigens durchaus berechtigt. Im Englischen ist es nämlich nicht "faculty", sondern "factorial", was vielmehr Sinn ergibt. Immerhin ist es Produkt der Faktoren. Also beim besten Willen kann ich nicht verstehen, wie diese Antwort soviele Upvotes verdient hat.